# What financial arrangement did Rambam have with his jeweler brother?

Tags: history, rabbis, rambam, employment, historical-figures

I was taught in yeshiva that as a young man, Rambam just studied Torah and was supported by his brother, who was a jewel merchant. Then his brother died at sea, so Rambam became a physician.

Some therefore claim that when the Rambam wrote that it is absolutely forbidden for one to say "I will just study Torah and not get a job", that doesn't apply if your family supports you, because the Rambam did that!

Recently someone told me that no, Rambam was never a "professional Torah student." His brother did the hard work of sailing the seas to obtain the jewels wholesale, and Rambam had a fairly calm job retailing them -- but he was still working.

Does anyone have sources on this, please?

Comment: The part of this that is potentially on topic is "[was Rambam a professional Torah student or did he work too]" which is a question about how he practiced Judaism, not details about "What financial arrangement did Rambam have with his jeweler brother?"

Answer (score 6):

[These Hebrew](http://www.bhol.co.il/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=2310209&whichpage=&forum_id=6410) [sites](http://wiki.oranim.ac.il/index.php?title=%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D) cite a letter from Rambam to Eliyahu the Dayan (Igrot Rambam, Rav Shilat Press, Volume I p. 311; emphasis added):

> והרעה הגדולה שבאה עליי באחרונה, ...והיא פטירת הצדיק, שטבע בים הודו 
>   ובידו ממון רב לי ולו ולאחרים והניח בת קטנה ואלמנתו אצלי..והוא היה האח. והוא היה התלמיד
>   והוא היה הנושא ונותן בשוק ומרוויח, ואני הייתי יושב לבטח...והלך לחיי העולם, והניחני נבהל בארץ
>   נוכריה.
>
> And the greatest tragedy that recently befell me was the death of the righteous one who drowned in the Indian Ocean while holding a great deal of property of *mine*, *his*, and *others'*, leaving me with his young daughter and widow, namely my brother. He was a student, he would do business in the markets and make profits while I dwelled securely ... he has gone to Eternal Life, leaving me confounded in a strange land.

So his brother had "money of his", "and did business while leaving me secure." I guess there are several ways that can be read:

- He had money that he had -- pledged to me? Owed me? Because he was supporting me?
- He had money that I had invested with him.
- He "left me secure" because he paid all the bills, or because he took care of the major risks?

Comment: " והוא היה הנושא ונותן בשוק ומרוויח, ואני הייתי יושב לבטח". Sounds like the brother did the work of retailing them in the market.

Answer (score 5):

See [here](http://hirhurim.blogspot.com/2006/11/rambam-on-being-paid-to-learn-or-teach.html):

> However, some ask, did not the Rambam do precisely that? Did he not learn Torah while his brother, David, worked as a merchant and supported him? Only after his brother died tragically did Rambam start working.
>
> ...
>
> The answer seems to be that this is not true.
>
> ...
>
> It was customary in merchants' families that one member, usually a father or elder brother, stayed put and the others traveled. Labrat and Judah (like Moses and David Maimonides later) had divided the family business between themselves in such a way.

It seems that this rests on supposition, based on what was common in those days.